# Local assignment affects type?

Tags: scala, generics

In the following example, f3 can take a Iterable[Array[Int]]

```
  def f3(o:Iterable[Iterable[Any]]):Unit = {}

  f3(Iterable(Array(123)))    // OK. Takes Iterable[Array[Int]]
```

but if I assign the Iterable[Array[Int]] to a local variable, it cannot:

```
  val v3 = Iterable(Array(123))
  f3(v3)    // Fails to take Takes Iterable[Array[Int]]
```

with the error:

```
  Error:(918, 10) type mismatch;
  found   : Iterable[Array[Int]]
  required: Iterable[Iterable[Any]]
  f3(x)
```

What the fudge? Why does the first example work, but not the seconds. It seems to have something to do with nested generics:

```
  def f(o:Iterable[Any]):Unit = {}
  f( Array(123))
  val v1 = Array(123)
  f(v1)  // OK

  def f2(o:Iterable[Any]):Unit = {}
  f2( Iterable(Array(123)))
  val v2 = Array(123)
  f(v2) // OK
```

With scala.2.11

Comment: Why `Iterable[Any]`? That's just as not use generics/type at all.

Comment: Any is the common interface of the object I need in my collections. In some contexts, Scala gets pissy if you don't specify a parameter type and infers Nothing instead, particularly when returning generics.

Comment: Mainly if you need `Any`, there is a design issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, it's important that `Array` doesn't extend `Iterable` (because it's a Java type). Instead there is an implicit conversion from `Array[A]` to `Iterable[A]`, so expected types matter.

In the first case: `Iterable(Array(123))` is an argument to `f3` and thus is typechecked with expected type `Iterable[Iterable[Any]]`. So `Array(123)` is typechecked with expected type `Iterable[Any]`. Well, its actual type is `Array[Int]` and the compiler inserts the conversion (because `Iterable[Int]` conforms to `Iterable[Any]`). So this is actually `Iterable(array2iterable(Array(123))` (I don't remember the exact name).

In the second case `f3` has the type `Iterable[Array[Int]]`: there is nothing to trigger the implicit conversion in the `val f3 = ...` line, right? And there is no implicit conversion from `Iterable[Array[Int]]` to `Iterable[Iterable[Int]]` (or, more generally from `Iterable[A]` to `Iterable[B]` when there is an implicit conversion from `A` to `B`), so the next line fails to compile. You could write this conversion yourself, but it wouldn't help e.g. to convert `Array[Array[Int]]` to `Iterable[Iterable[Int]]`.

And of course, if you use `Iterable[Any]`, there is again nothing to trigger the implicit conversion!

Comment: This does not explain why explicit conversion happens in the first case, but no it second: "there is no implicit conversion from ... to ..." may be correct, but then why does the first case work?

Comment: @Dima The first case works because there is an implicit conversion from `Array[Int]` to `Iterable[Int]`. So since we use an array where an iterable is epexted, the conversion can be used. In the the second case the line `val v3 = Iterable(Array(123))` does not expect `Iterable[Int]` anywhere, so no implicit conversion is needed for that line to work. We then get a problem on the next line, but by then it's too late to add an implicit conversion around `Array(123)` (because that already executed on the previous line). At best we could one around `v3`, but as Alexey says, no suitable one exists.

Comment: @Dima Er... it does? "So Array(123) is typechecked with expected type Iterable[Any]. Well, its actual type is Array[Int] and the compiler inserts the conversion (because Iterable[Int] conforms to Iterable[Any])."

Comment: @sepp2k The assignment does not expect the type, so there is no conversion, understood. But, the next line `f3(v3)` _does_ expect the type, and, AFAICS is no different from `f3(Iterable(Array(123)))` - `v3` is exactly that type.  If an implicit conversion is possible in one case, why is it not possible in the other?

Comment: @AlexyRomanov "So Array(123) is typechecked with expected type Iterable[Any]" there is no `Array(123)`. Only `Iterable(Array(123))`. Just like in the other case.

Comment: Also, note, that if you declare `f3` to accept `Iterable[Array[Int]]`, then it compiles in both cases. The problem is not the converting `Array` to `Iterable`, it is converting `Int` to `Any`, as @evan058 explains.

Comment: @Dima "there is no Array(123)" There is, it's the argument of `Iterable.apply`.

Comment: @Dima If you think the problem is converting `Int` to `Any`, try `Iterable[Iterable[Int]]` and `Iterable[Array[Any]]`. If you give `Iterable[Array[Int]]`, there is not conversion at all.

Answer (score 4):

This has to do with the way type inference/unification works in Scala.

When you define a variable and leave out the type, Scala applies the most specific type possible:

```
scala> val v1 = Iterable(Array(123))
v1: Iterable[Array[Int]] = List(Array(123))
```

However, when you specify the expected type (eg by passing the value to a function with a defined parameter type) Scala unifies the given parameter with the expected type (if possible) :

```
scala> val v2 : Iterable[Iterable[Any]] = Iterable(Array(123))
v2: Iterable[Iterable[Any]] = List(WrappedArray(123))
```

Since `Int` is a subtype of `Any`, unification occurs and the code runs just fine.

If you want your function to accept anything that is a subtype of `Any` (without Scala's unification help) you will have to define this behavior explicitly.

**Edit:**

While what I am saying is partially true, see @AlexyRomanov's answer for a more correct assessment. It seems that the "unification" between `Array` and `Iterable` is really an implicit conversion being called when you pass `Iterable(Array(123))` as a parameter (see the effect of this in my declaration of `v2`).

Suppose you have a bit of code where the compiler expects type `B` but finds type `A` instead. Before throwing an error, the compiler checks a collection of implicit conversion functions for one with the type `A => B`. If the compiler finds a satisfactory conversion, the conversion is applied automatically (and silently).

The reason `f3` doesn't like `v1` is because it is too late to call an implicit conversion on the inner `Array[Int]` and no existing implicit conversion exists for `Iterable[Array[Int]] => Iterable[Iterable[Int]]`, though it would be trivial to implement, as I show below:

```
scala> implicit def ItAr2ItIt[T](ItAr: Iterable[Array[T]]): Iterable[Iterable[T]] = ItAr.map(_.toIterable)
ItAr2ItIt: [T](ItAr: Iterable[Array[T]])Iterable[Iterable[T]]

scala> def f3(o:Iterable[Iterable[Any]]):Unit = println("I like what I see!")
f3: (o: Iterable[Iterable[Any]])Unit

scala> val v3 = Iterable(Array(123))
v3: Iterable[Array[Int]] = List(Array(123))

scala> f3(v3)
I like what I see!
```